# What’s Doctor Who doing in the Talmud?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Among the early *amoraim* is
ר׳ יוחנן נפחא
(Rabbi Yochanan Nafcha), brother-in-law to the *amora* Resh Lakish.
His name translates as John Smith;
*cf.* [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_(given_name))
and [Morfix](http://www.morfix.co.il/en/%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%97).
This *obviously* refers to
[the Doctor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_(Doctor_Who)),
since “John Smith” is one of his favorite aliases.

But what’s Doctor Who doing in the Talmud?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I’ve got to wonder how large the intersection is between Doctor Who fandom and those who appreciate Purim Torah.

Comment: I think i once saw him trying to run away from a Dalek gas station in Israel.

Comment: In Loshon HaKodesh "Who" is "Me", although in English we would say who am I. So I believe that the question is what am I doing in the Talmud?

Comment: Now I know why the Doctor always has a companion: ת״ר איזהו שוטה היוצא יחידי בלילה והלן בבית הקברות והמקרע את כסותו איתמר רב הונא אמר עד שיהו כולן בבת אחת ר׳ יוחנן אמר אפי׳ באחת מהן ([_Chagiga_](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%92%D7%99%D7%92%D7%94_%D7%92_%D7%91))

Comment: Someone clearly doesn't understand what a [TARDIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS) is.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu "He" in Hebrew is "who." We (or they) must be dealing with a person who refers to himself in the third person. (That reminds me of [this video](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/233927/jewish/Hebrew-Lesson.htm).)

Comment: I thought TARDIS is just an Anglicized form of TALMUD "it's bigger on the inside".

Comment: Awww...this question looked like it was going to get some perfectly Purim rediculous(Puridiculous?) and entertaining answers.  What makes this question any more unreal than the other PT questions?

Comment: I was hoping for something about _Mar_ = the Master, but everything I came up with was too forced to be funny.

Comment: @Gary -- All Purim Torah questions get closed under such tags a few days after Purim.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu, this question was closed earlier than the others, and for a different reason.  have no grounds for complaint or dispute, but I am disappointed; if I think of a suitable answer I'll ask for this to be reopened next Purim.

Comment: See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/does-purim-torah-need-to-be-otherwise-on-topic#comment10146_3441 for why it was closed.